# Join using a non-equality join

Tags: sql, oracle

Hey stuck on another SQL question....

Show the transactions for all customer accounts. Solve using JOIN USING. Sort by name, customer #, account type, and transaction number.

Note: Amount comes from a non equality joined table. Honestly not sure if the syntax is correct and also need to get the date formatted like 16-11-25. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT
    First_name as "First",  
    Surname as "Last", 
    Customer_number as "Cust #", 
    wa.Account_type as "Type", 
    Transaction_number as "Trans #",
    Transaction_type as "T",  
    Date_created('DD-MM-YY') as "Date",
    Amount as "Amount"
from
    WGB_CUSTOMER wc
    join WGB_ACCOUNT wa using (Customer_number)
    join WGB_TRANSACTION wt using (Customer_number)
    join WGB_ASSETS on (Amount>0)
order by
    1,2,4,5;
```

Comment: `JOIN ... USING` is a shorthand syntax unique to Oracle's PL/SQL. For maximum portability you should avoid it and use traditional `JOIN ... ON` syntax. That said, this looks like a homework question.

Comment: We can't answer your question for you as we don't know your DB table design.

Comment: Also, you should avoid doing any date-formatting in SQL because it means you lose type-safety. You should ensure the original datatypes are passed to the query's consumer as much as possible. And `yy-MM-dd` is not a valid date format in any country's system, you should use ISO 8601 (`yyyy-MM-dd` if you need a uniform date representation - but again, only do the conversion in the view layer, not in the query).

Comment: Ok thanks. I still get "Date_Created": invalid identifier on line 8 when I put the date in the format of yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: @Dai, the `using` keyword is not unique to oracle.  I work with another database engine that supports it.  Also, why is it relevant that the OP has an academic motivation?   Also, what's this nonsense about portability?  If you have SQL Server database, would you avoid using datediff() because Oracle does not support it?

Comment: @DNkG, the to_char function will format your date for you.  Also, `Amount comes from a non equality joined table.` is unclear.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk, thanks I will look at my notes on how to use the to_char function. Also I am still very new to oracle and the sql syntax but the table that Amount comes from does not have a primary key to relate it to the other tables in the database. I also just realized I have to make the Transaction_number unique but by typing unique in front of the Transaction_number is throwing another error.

Comment: @philipxy The OP is new to SQL, so I doubt it he really wants cross join. At least I hope he doesn't... ;)

Comment: @BobC But the JOIN ON *is* cross joining. And I do expect it's an error.

Comment: Please show your table columns. Please explain what "using JOIN USING" means exactly--do you mean, instead of joins on equality of same-named columns? Or, you have to use it and maybe column renamings for join on equality of any pair of columns? Ie when may you *not* use USING? Also, surely you should be joining on some other WGB_ASSETS column, not cross joining--which is what your JOIN ON is doing now, because there's no column shared with another table?

Answer (score 0):

The USING clause is not unique to Oracle, it's standard SQL. It's really just a short cut, so

```
from 
    WGB_CUSTOMER wc
    join WGB_ACCOUNT wa using (Customer_number)
```

is a short cut for

```
    WGB_CUSTOMER wc
    join WGB_ACCOUNT wa 
      on wc.Customer_number = wa.Customer_number
```

It relies on the fact that keys have the same name in both tables.
It's generally recommended to avoid that shortcut because it can lead to mistakes.

Coming back to your specific example, I think what you want to join to WGB_ASSETS and then test the amount, something like:

```
SELECT
    First_name as "First",  
    Surname as "Last", 
    Customer_number as "Cust #", 
    wa.Account_type as "Type", 
    Transaction_number as "Trans #",
    Transaction_type as "T",  
/*    Date_created('DD-MM-YY') as "Date",   < incorrect syntax   */
    to_char( date_created, 'DD-MM-YY' ) as "Date"
    Amount as "Amount"
from
    WGB_CUSTOMER wc
    join WGB_ACCOUNT wa 
      on wc.Customer_number = wa.Customer_number
    join WGB_TRANSACTION wt 
      on wc.Customer_number = wt.Customer_number       
    join WGB_ASSETS wg
      on wc.Customer_number = wg.Customer_number
    where wg.Amount>0
order by
    1,2,4,5;
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the help! My only issue now is how to make Transaction_number unique in this query?